# NextJS: Invalid hook call right after create-next-app@latest

Tags: next.js, react-hooks

JS learner here.
I'm using `npx create-next-app@latest` and selecting the following:

```
✔ What is your project named? … babys-first-todo-app
✔ Would you like to use TypeScript? … Yes
✔ Would you like to use ESLint? … Yes
✔ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? … Yes
✔ Would you like to use `src/` directory? … Yes
✔ Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) … No
✔ Would you like to customize the default import alias? … No 
Creating a new Next.js app in /.../babys-first-todo-app.
```

Package installations complete successfully.

After making no adjustments whatsoever, I ran `next dev` from the root dir of the project and am immediately greeted with:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at useContext (.../babys-first-todo-app/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1618:21)
    at Html (webpack-internal:///../../.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:719:114)
    at renderWithHooks (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5731:15)
    at renderElement (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5946:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5785:7)
    at renderElement (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5946:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
    at renderContextProvider (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5920:3)
    at renderElement (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6017:11)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
    at renderContextProvider (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5920:3)
    at renderElement (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6017:11)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
    at retryTask (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6528:5)
    at performWork (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6576:7)
    at ....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6902:12
    at scheduleWork (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:77:3)
    at startWork (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6901:3)
    at ....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6996:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.renderToReadableStream (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6949:10)
    at renderToString (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:82:55)
    at ....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:910:112
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:86:20)
    at renderToHTML (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:910:57)
    at async doRender (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1024:34)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.incrementalCache.incrementalCache (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1147:28)
    at async ....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache/index.js:97:36
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at useContext (.../babys-first-todo-app/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1618:21)
    at Html (webpack-internal:///../../.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:719:114)
    at renderWithHooks (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5731:15)
    at renderElement (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5946:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5785:7)
    at renderElement (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5946:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
    at renderContextProvider (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5920:3)
    at renderElement (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6017:11)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
    at renderContextProvider (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5920:3)
    at renderElement (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6017:11)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
    at retryTask (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6528:5)
    at performWork (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6576:7)
    at ....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6902:12
    at scheduleWork (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:77:3)
    at startWork (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6901:3)
    at ....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6996:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.renderToReadableStream (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6949:10)
    at renderToString (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:82:55)
    at ....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:910:112
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:86:20)
    at renderToHTML (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:910:57)
    at async doRender (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1024:34)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.incrementalCache.incrementalCache (....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1147:28)
    at async ....nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache/index.js:97:36
```

If it's helpful:

//package.json:

```
{
  "name": "babys-first-todo-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.4.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.6",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.44.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.9",
    "next": "13.4.9",
    "postcss": "8.4.25",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  }
}
```

// next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

//_app.tsx (unaltered)

```
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

// _document.tsx

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head />
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

index.tsx is good ol' Nextjs' getting started page.

Wasn't sure if running `next dev` would use the local next install or global install so I tried:

- `npm upgrade -g` followed by `next dev` in case my global install was out of date.
- `npm run dev` trying to use the local install. Same result.
- Tried running a `next dev` on a nextjs project I started a few months ago, which worked fine.

Reading the [React Docs - Invalid hook call warning](https://legacy.reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#mismatching-versions-of-react-and-react-dom)
I tried uninstalling all instances of react and react-dom, then reinstalling. I also tried running `npm dedupe`

`npm ls react` returns:

```
├─┬ next@13.4.9
│ ├── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └─┬ styled-jsx@5.1.1
│   └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
└── react@18.2.0
```

Along the same vien, I tried changing the @types package versions in package.json to match their respective npm packages -> Deleting node_modules -> Reinstalling

I also tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling, and using create-nextjs-app@latest several times. Unfortunately, same result.
In one instance, I selected 'Yes' at the "Use App Router" of create-nextjs-app. Running `next dev` returned an error about needing to enable the appdir in next.config.js. After remedying that error, I returned to the invalid hook error.